# Python socket.gethostname

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to code a small web server in python to catch an HTTP post.
But I'm having an issue with the socket.gethostname part of it

here is my sample code

```
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 8089))
serversocket.listen(1)


while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(164)
    print buf
```

If i change

```
serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 8089))
```

to

```
serversocket.bind(("localhost", 8089))
```

Everything is fine I can telnet into it, but I need to be able to connect from another web server on the internet so  I need to use socket.gethostname but this block my telnet.

Comment: "another web server on the internet" or just your LAN?

Comment: Also "I'm trying to code a small web server in python" - Have you tried using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/)?

Comment: On the internet !? i will look into Flask right now

Comment: Well, your router will need to forward a port to your server, which is why I asked. Otherwise your firewall will block it.

Comment: Try `serversocket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 8089))` that should bind to all of your external addresses.

Comment: But as others have mentioned, your local server can't receive incoming connections from the internet if a network firewall or NAT is in the way. You will need to configure your firewall/NAT or if you control the protocol between the web server and this server... have this server make the connection instead of the other way around.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney it worked using    serversocket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 8089))

Comment: I was configuring Raspberry Pi as server, and there `socket.gethostname()` simply returns `raspberrypi`, haha. So, be careful, guys :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using a clever trick to get your servers "real" address when potentially several network interfaces are open. `serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 8089))` can be broken down to

```
hostname = socket.gethostname()
dns_resolved_addr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
serversocket.bind((dns_resolved_addr, 8089))
```

You get your local hostname and then ask DNS what it thinks your IP address is, and bind to that. That's the IP address external connections will use so you should use it too.

But it doesn't always work. DNS may not know what your server name is or your server may have a different name in DNS. One example is my home network where I don't have a DNS server and the DHCP addresses handed out by my modem don't appear in a name server anywhere. A similar problem exists if your corporate DHCP doesn't register your hostname with its local DNS.

On my machine, when I go through the steps I get

```
>>> socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
'127.0.1.1'
```

Notice it was `127.0.1.1` ... I think that's some weird Ubuntu thing to keep its routing tables from getting confused. Anyway, one solution is to try to resolve the address and if you don't like it, fall back to a default.

```
>>> my_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
>>> if my_ip.startswith('127.0.'):
...     my_ip = '0.0.0.0'
... 
>>> my_ip
'0.0.0.0'
```